# Make div stick to the bottom of the page but stay in the flow

Tags: html, css, gwt

Okay, I'll first begin with an image and the code so I can explain my problem better.

[image]

```
<div class="overall">
    <div class="areas">
        <div class="area">
            Area 1
        </div>
        <div class="area">
            Area 2
        </div>
        <div class="area">
            Area 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="log">
        <div class="logheader">
            Logheader
        </div>
        <div class="logbody">
            Logbody
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
            <div>Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


body, html {
    max-height: 100vh;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.area, .logheader {
    height: 72px;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.log {
    height: 572px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.logbody {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.areas {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.overall {
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

So what I need to achieve (only with CSS) is that first the log part always stays directly under the areas part. Once the browser window becomes smaller and the bottom of the browser window "touches" the bottom of the log part, the log part should become attached to the bottom of the browser window. When the height of the browser window is reduced further the log part should keep its fixed size and the areas part should become smaller with a scrollbar. Only the areas part should have a scrollbar (once its too small for the content) and the log body should also have one as you can already see from the screenshot. But the page itself should never have a scrollbar, which is why the max height of the whole page is set to 100vh.

What you see in the code is what I have tried until now, but this does not work as intended.

**EDIT**: As everyone is saying that this won't work without JS etc. I should add that I will have to use this in GWT lateron, so does anyone know how to do this with GWT?

Comment: You need javascript to do that

Comment: It's not possible without JS.. you need to find out when your content reaches the bottom with js.

Comment: Okay, that's quite bad.. but I will have to implement this with GWT anyway, is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 0):

a little bit anomalous way to do this is - in gwt you can use listeners for browser events -

```
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/BrowserEvents.html#CHANGE
```

and then you can fetch browser height and width by  ----

```
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html
```

-- Window.getClientHeight() 
-- Window.getClientWidth()

for the log part you can set Scroll Panel sizes by -

```
 Window.getClientHeight().
```

Answer (score 0):

This design can be implemented using [flex-box layout model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which is supported by all modern browsers.

If you need to support very old browsers, you will have to use a panel that implements RequiresResize interface in GWT and recalculate the height of the scroll panel when window is resized or new content loaded.

Comment: And? I know it can be done with flex-box. If you had a problem, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Pure CSS should be possible using media-queries: [CSS3 @media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

(2) As you're going to use GWT, theres another solution in sight:

first, Window  [GWT Window (JavaDoc)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html) has all code you need.

Use *addResizeHandler* to listen on resize events. on resize, use *getClientHeight* and *getClientWidth* to check for your desired dimensions.

**In either way:**

Once the viewport-dimension is smallish, use an alternative (secondary) css-tag on a parent element of your liking (or even to the element itself). This css-tag will then change your elements position-attribute to your needs (i.e. position: fixed)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with GWT and CSS only. I was messing around with GWT and created a test page (Sorry, image upload wasn't working).

Basically the content in the center will shrink if I resize the window and the footer will stay exactly where it belongs and remain the same height and width.

First I had to do this in CSS:

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Then, in my Java code, I added a HorizontalPanel to another HorizontalPanel, then added a widget into the parent HorizontalPanel that acts like a footer. I then set the HorizontalPanel height and width to 100%. Afterwards I set the widget (footer) css attribute width to border-box and the height to 50px.

GWT also contains WindowResizeListeners and height/width getters that you can apply directly into your Java code. Using something similar to this:

```
public void onWindowResize() {

    HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();    

    int height = Window.getClientHeight();
    int width = Window.getClientWidth();

    hp.setHeight(height);
    hp.setWidth(width);
}
```

This would allow you to change the height and width of a panel compared to your window while keeping another untouched.